# Configure a synology NAS reverse proxy to not replace URL

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, nas, synology-diskstation

I'm a little confused about how to configure subdomains to multiple servers on the same physical machine.

Currently, I have a domain name which is setup to use DDNS. I have the built in reverse proxy available on the nas. The default synology entry for the reverse proxy means that when I go to https://example.com, it then changes it to example.com:5001.

However, I only want communication to go through port 443 on my network. When I navigate to the url example.com, it actually redirects to example.com:5001 which gets refused by my router, port 5001 not being open.

Also, I cannot figure out how to make a subdomain go to a different server (same device). I'm trying to get subdomain sub.example.com to end up at example.com:3000 when I navigate to sub.example.com, it does not get routed to my device at all unless I create a subdomain forward record, (at least that's what google domains calls it). This just routes sub.example.com to example.com, which then contacts my nas with the hostname example.com which then gets proxied to example.com:5001 regardless of whatever reverse proxy entry I have for sub.example.com

1) How do I get my nas to proxy all traffic to local services over port 443? Is this possible? (as in my browser shows example.com, but it's actually hosted on the server at 5001.)

2) How do I get a subdomain to route to a different port on the nas?